# "cavil": Out of fashion?

Tags: usage

Found the word in a book from 1944. I don't recall hearing it before, even though I speak English as a second language since 50 years. (I may forget a meaning, but not a word.) Meaning was obvious from context, also Internet exists :-)

What I can't check offhand, though, is if the word is still in wide use or if synonyms prevail.

Comment: [Google Ngrams suggests that it's been getting less common for about 200 years.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cavil_INF&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t3%3B%2Ccavil_INF%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcavil%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcavils%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcavilling%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcavilled%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcaviling%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcaviled%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: [Even though I've spoken English as a second language]

Comment: @stangdon: Ah. Right. Could have done that myself, if I had had the idea, but it's difficult to interpret Ngrams in absolute terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb is somewhat formal and old-fashioned, and mostly to be found in printed or published material, e.g. in a legal context. It is familiar to educated people, especially older ones. The noun probably the same.

> It is furlough that made Sunak the government’s star player in this
> crisis. Critics may point out that it was he who wanted to kill the
> policy last autumn, but the chancellor is a quick study. Where once
> **he cavilled** at the cost, now he is taking no chances. This was a Budget to seal the narrative.

Financial Times (UK) March 3 2021

> In his reports **Mr MacGregor cavilled** at certain aspects of Mr Creed’s
> approach to his calculation of the trading profit percentages,
> specifically the fact that these were assessed by reference to the
> opening figure for the fund for each period, plus capital injections
> and ignored withdrawals in the subsequent annual period.

Legal judgment (2006) UK High Court

Modern synonyms include find fault with, quibble, complain, or moan (verbs), and quibble or complaint (nouns).

[Cavil synonyms and antonyms (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/cavil)

Comment: Upped. Mind to edit in which alternatives are preferred in more colloquial use?